# Anaconda navigator is not opening

Tags: python, anaconda

I have had this problem for quite some time now. Every time I restart my PC, the anaconda navigator, prompt or any other application don't open. Instead, the python shell opens up. The message in the shell goes like this.

```
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation
```

Well, I went to the given link and there it said to run `conda activate myenv` where `myenv` is the path directory. When I try this out in the terminal, the error message is something like this:

`'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Can somebody direct me and help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed python 2.7 or python 3 version before installing anaconda navigator and also choose appropriate python verion which u have  preinstalled...and then select accordingly while installing conda navigator

Comment: While installing Anaconda, it said that Anaconda will be used as the default python option. Is it necessary for me to install python 3?

Comment: Yes its important to install python 3 first because sometimes it does not work without that i also faced this problem once long back

Comment: I installed pyhton3 but still the moment I restarted the Pc, my anaconda navigator stooped working and the same python interpreter popped up saying navigator is not activated @Code wizard

Comment: So until u restarted ur system was tha conda navicator working correctly plz specify and also can u try reintalling conda app selecting python 3 as a default version used..

Comment: yes, I tried this, I have reinstalled at least 3 times now. I chose python3 as the default version. Still, it said there is some activation problem

Comment: yes, same problem and I'm now trying to download anaconda installer again